# Hyperparameter tuning results yield no improvement over spot-check

Tags: scikit-learn, time-series, hyperparameter-tuning

There is a balanced binary classified dataset as seen below.

[image: Target Variable count]

Things I have tried using [RandomForestClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) as chosen model:

- [TimeSeriesSplit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html) with `n_splits`=3 and 10
- [MinMaxScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler), [MaxAbsScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MaxAbsScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MaxAbsScaler), [StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler), [RobustScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.RobustScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.RobustScaler), [QuantileTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.QuantileTransformer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.QuantileTransformer), [PowerTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PowerTransformer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.PowerTransformer)

Snippet of RandomizedSearchCV set-up:

`scorer = {...,
'precision': make_scorer(precision_score, average = 'weighted'),
...,
}
RandomizedSearchCV(model, grid, scoring=scorer, cv=TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=10), refit='precision', verbose=10)`

However despite all these efforts, precision (the main metric I have chosen to use) are all very similar. Inital spotcheck precision results were: ~.55-.56. Hyperparameter tuning results in the same range too, **no improvement** at all! Other "curious" metrics like F0.5 score and recall all have no improvements too with little variation.

The biggest noticeable difference so far are `n_splits` 3 and 10. With all else equal, the range of precision is bumped up to ~.57-.59 with `n_splits=10`. Hyperparameter tuning results also within ~.57-.59!

I am stumped. Does anyone have ideas on how to find out what may be the issue(s)? I can provide more information if needed.

Edit 1 (grid):

```
# Number of trees in random forest
n_estimators = [x for x in range(400, 2000, 200)]

# Number of features to consider at every split
max_features = ['log2']

# Maximum number of levels in tree
max_depth = [x for x in range(10, 110, 10)]
max_depth.append(None)

# Minimum number of samples required to split a node
min_samples_split = [2, 5, 10]

# Minimum number of samples required at each leaf node
min_samples_leaf = [4]

# Method of selecting samples for training each tree
bootstrap = [True, False]
```

Comment: What's the hyperparameter space, and how many points?

Comment: 28 values across `n_estimators`, `max_features`, `max_depth`, `min_samples_split`, `min_samples_leaf`, `bootstrap`. RandomizedSearchCV prints out: `Fitting 10 folds for each of 10 candidates, totalling 100 fits`.  I have edited the question to provide the grid details.

Comment: First, use more than the default n_iter=10; if you have the time for it, 60 is a good default, but if this took long to run already you could do with 30-40.  Second, look at your train fold scores to gauge how much you're overfitting; that can guide new choices on hyperparameter space.  Third, and more data-dependent: try smaller values of max_depth and/or larger values of min_split or min_leaf (in these two, preferably float values, which give percentages of the training data rather than fixed numbers).  Consider also adding another max_features option.

Comment: I will try this. Thank you! Sidenote, there are 18 features. Perhaps I can also utilize feature selections to narrow down features. In the meantime, 2 follow up questions: 1. How did you rationalize to try out these new hyperparam spaces? This is perhaps my lack in knowledge with RFC. 2. " look at your train fold scores..." How I can tell if it is overfitting is if the metrics change very little in the RandomizedSearchCV's verbose output?

Comment: 1. Just my experience using RF and understanding of the algorithm; but again, it will eventually come down to your data.  2. I'm not familiar though with the verbose output...I would add `return_train_scores=True` to the RSCV, and examine the resulting `cv_results_` table.